# How can I examine a (simple) server side application on my computer?

Tags: c#, proxy, network-programming

I'm developing an HTTP server side application, & I've only 3 questions to complete the program.

I'm a web developer.
So, I need any Network programmer(*programming language isn't necessary, only concepts*)

My program: is a simple windows application on the proxy server, to run an algorithm that caches the most browsed website.

Questions:-

1. Am i need to create log files & access log files to do that?
2. I'm developing the app. on my computer using IP Address:127.0.0.1 & Port No.:8080 & it runs, Will it run on the actual Proxy Server?
3. How can I examine the application on the Virtual machine windows server [Some body told me to install APPACHE server !!!]?

Breifly, the project is:-

- HTTP listener listens to the traffic.
- stores request's URLs.
- Remove Duplicates in URLs // BCOZ we want to Count The Internal URLs -which should be with different extensions - of the most browsed site.
- Count all Mother URLs with diff. extentions.
- Get the largest URL visited.
- Cache the Page of this URL.
                     ********* IS MY IDEA TRUE?************

Thank you,
Best Regards.

Comment: is this a windows virtual machine.. are you familiar with IIS and event logs.. ect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

1. No. You don't necessarily need to create a file. You can store your data in memory if you want.
2. If your proxy server is set up like your development machine, yes. If your proxy server is significantly different, your program will not run.
3. One way is to log in to the Virtual machine windows server directly. Another way is to make your application write data to a place that is more convenient.

Yes, your idea is true. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you Mr.GreenReign, but I cann't understand third answer..


what do you mean by logging in virtual machine directly,
My project returns all requests from a specific Port No.,


how can I adjust the program to recieve requests whereever it was installed, OR 


How can I give the function of listening requests parameters(portNo.) of the server that the program is located?